How can I add click event on UIImageView inside UITableviewCell?
I want to add some click event inside table view cell, I research the answer from internet, so I   add "isUserInteractionEnabled = true" in UIImageView to let UIImageView can accept the click event and add "cancelsTouchesInView = true" in UITapGestureRecognizer to stop click event to cell, but it seems not work, can mentor tell me how can I implement it to add click event to object inside the cell?
My test example is as follow:
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var list: [dao] = [dao]()
    
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let view = UITableView()
        view.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        view.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        view.register(ListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "listCell")
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        list.append(dao(featured: "featured1", name: "featured1"))
        list.append(dao(featured: "featured2", name: "featured2"))
        
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as? ListCell {
            let row: dao = self.list[indexPath.row]
            cell.update(row: row, idx: indexPath.row + 1)
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

class ListCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let featruedIV: UIImageView = {
        let view: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return view
    }()
    
    let nameLbl: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setupView()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        
        self.addSubview(featruedIV)
        featruedIV.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-12)
            make.height.width.equalTo(90)
        }
        
        let tg: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressed))
        tg.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        featruedIV.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        
        self.addSubview(nameLbl)
        nameLbl.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalTo(featruedIV.snp.centerY)
            make.left.equalTo(featruedIV.snp.right).offset(12)
        }
    }
    
    func update(row: dao, idx: Int) {
        nameLbl.text = row.name
        featruedIV.image = UIImage(named: row.featured)
    }
    
    @objc func pressed() {
        print("pressed")
    }
}

class dao {
    var featured: String
    var name: String
    
    init(featured: String, name: String) {
        self.featured = featured
        self.name = name
    }
}


I have made a simple example to test the code as follow.


In your ListCell, you are adding elements to the root of the cell instead of the contentView. If you want the taps to work, just add your elements to the contentView.
private func setupView() {
    // here
    contentView.addSubview(featruedIV)
    featruedIV.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(12)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-12)
        make.height.width.equalTo(90)

        // Also if you want to remove warnings from Snapkit in the console
        // You can set priority of height to high.
        // Like this:
        // make.width.equalTo(90)
        // make.height.equalTo(90).priority(.high)  
    }
    
    let tg: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressed))
    // It is no needed
    //tg.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    featruedIV.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
    
    // and here
    contentView.addSubview(nameLbl)
    nameLbl.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.centerY.equalTo(featruedIV.snp.centerY)
        make.left.equalTo(featruedIV.snp.right).offset(12)
    }
}

Explanation:
If you look at the UITableViewCell API, it says:

Specifically in your case, the contentView was placed above the UIImageView and was intercepting all events.
